# Échouée ou échoué ?

Tags: traduction, conjugaison

Bonjour,

J'ai un petit souci de traduction.
Si je ne me trompe pas, « Authentication failed » se traduirait littéralement par « Authentification ratée ». Cependant, je voudrais évidemment éviter l'emploi du mot « rater » ici, et voudrais le remplacer par la version plus soutenue « échouer ».
Voici donc ma question:

> Authentification échouée

ou

> Authentification échoué

Évidemment, la deuxième solution semble fausse, mais sachant que l'on doit utiliser « L'authentification a échoué » dans une phrase plus complète, je me demandais quelles étaient les règles de grammaire sous-jacentes.
« Authentification » est peut-être un peu trop littéral comme traduction, si vous en avez une autre, je suis preneur. Cependant, la question reste valide avec d'autre noms tels que « préparation », « connexion », etc... (même « cuisson » !)

Édition: Contrairement à ce que j'ai annoncé plus haut, je pense que la phrase complète plus familière est bien « L'Authentification a raté ». C'est pourquoi j'aimerais que quelqu'un m'éclaire sur les règles associées.

Comment: Je ne m'étais jamais posé cette question. Je mettrais un *e* quand même. N'est-ce pas un adjectif dans ce contexte ? Est-ce que finalement ce n'est pas *l'authentification est ratée* ?

Comment: Peut-être qu'une partie de la réponse  peut être tirée de la similarité avec « J'_ai_ raté ma présentation » ? Cependant, il est possible que « raté » soit ici un adjectif.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour répondre directement à la question;

> Authentification échouée

La raison est simple, `Authentification` est un nom féminin, donc `échouer` y vole son genre. [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Authentication%20failed%20translation%20french), parfois et même souvent, donne de bonnes traductions pour confirmer certains doutes.

Pour ce qui est de la traduction vers `raté`, je crois que ce n'est pas que ce soit la résultante directe. `Failure` qui est l'équivalent nominal de `failed` est traduisible par (un) échec.

Pour ce qui est de la façon que j'écrirais la version traduite, j'irais avec:

> Échec d'authentification

ou

> Échec à l'authentification

Certain sites tel que [MyMemory](http://mymemory.translated.net/en/English/French/authentication-failed) peuvent donner de multiples exemples avec contextes pour t'inspirer.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec la première partie de la réponse ; quant à la seconde partie, je pense que la proposition de Poutmmmm est plus idiomatique : **Échec de l'authentification**.

Answer (score 11):

Je traduirai par :

> Échec de l'authentification !

Comment: ou encore "Echec d'authentification"

Comment: Ces traductions sont effectivement possibles, c'est vrai. @Random, c'est vrai, mais je verrais plus cela dans un contexte d'autres opérations, quand l'authentification n'est pas le but principal. Quid des règles de grammaires associées, cependant ?